# Leaflet.markercluster cluster of clusters

Tags: leaflet

I'm using multiple Leaflet.markercluster groups to cluster data from different layers, meaning a given cluster contains only markers from a single layer.  I'm able to customize the icon for each type (i.e. provide iconCreateFunction) so the user can distinguish them visually.  So far, so good.

What I'd like to do is *combine* clusters of different types, or even markers, when their icons are very close to one another.  That is, maxClusterRadius for homogeneous might be 80 pixels, but heterogeneous clusters would use a radius of something like 5 pixels.

Has anyone tackled this, or at least given serious thought to what a solution might look like?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? If so, please post, and accept, an answer, which would help others. Thanks.